# a circle and a parabola have 3 intersection points

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, conic-sections, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

Is it possible that a circle and a parabola on a euclidean plane have 3 intersection points and the center of the circle does not lie on the axis of parabola?

Comment: As a comment, take any point on the parabola, calculate the slope of the tangent and then calculate the normal. When you intersect that normal with the parabola, you find the circle's center.

Comment: One of the intersections must of course be touching, i.e., non-traversal ...

Comment: Yes of course, I used as my example $(x+1.5)^2+(y-2.25)^2=125/16$ with the standard parabola $y=x^2$ which I would post as an answer but Rae beat me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, that is possible.

[image]

Comment: To put some skin on those bones, pick any point $p$ on the parabola $P$, other than the apex. Consider the line $L$ perpendicular to the tangent of $P$ at $p$. Any circle centred on that line will intersect the parabola at $p$. If the circles centre is on the axis it will intersect at one other point, by symmetry. If its on the other side of the axis, it will intersect $P$ at two other points, making three in total.

Comment: This is a particular case (double points) : you should "left-shift" a little your circle...

Comment: @user24142 thank you for the skin, I wanted to let Kelly come with a generalized approach herself